# Aggregate root implementation with slick

Tags: scala, domain-driven-design, slick

I am trying to implement a simple aggregation root in slick. 
But I don't really know what is the best way to do that.

Here is my domain objects:

```
case class Project(id: UUID,
               name: String,
               state: ProjectState,
               description: String,
               team: String,
               tags: Set[String]
```

I would like to store the "tags" in a separate table and build up the "Project" objects from "projects_table" and "project_tags_table"

Here is my table definition:

```
class ProjectTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[ProjectTableRecord](tag, Some("octopus_service"), "projects") {

      def id: Rep[UUID] = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey)

      def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("name")

      def state: Rep[ProjectState] = column[ProjectState]("state")

      def description: Rep[String] = column[String]("description")

      def team: Rep[String] = column[String]("team")



      override def * : ProvenShape[ProjectTableRecord] = (id, name, state, description, team, created, lastModified) <> (
        (ProjectTableRecord.apply _).tupled, ProjectTableRecord.unapply
      )
    }

class ProjectTagTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[ProjectTag](tag, Some("octopus_service"), "project_tags") {

  def projectID: Rep[UUID] = column[UUID]("project_id")

  def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("name")

  def project = foreignKey("PROJECT_FK", projectID, TableQuery[ProjectTable])(_.id, onUpdate = ForeignKeyAction.Restrict, onDelete = ForeignKeyAction.Cascade)

  override def * : ProvenShape[ProjectTag] = (projectID, name) <> (
    ProjectTag.tupled, ProjectTag.unapply
  )
}
```

How can I generate "Project" objects from joining these 2 tables?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a misconception on the level of responsibility. Slick allows you to access relational database (to some extent the same way as SQL allows you to do it). It's basically a DAO layer.

Aggregate root is really a level above this (it's a domain thing, not db level thing - although they often are the same to large extent).

So basically you need to have a *level above* `Slick` tables that would allow you to perform different queries and *aggregate* the results into single being.

Before we start though - you should create and store somewhere your `TableQuery` objects, perhaps like this:

```
lazy val ProjectTable = TableQuery[ProjectTable]
lazy val ProjectTagTable = TableQuery[ProjectTagTable]
```

You could put them probably somewhere near you `Table definitions`.

So first as I mentioned your Aggregate Root being `Project` needs be pulled by something. Let's call it `ProjectRepository`.

Let's say it will have a method `def load(id: UUID): Future[Project]`.

This method would perhaps look like this:

```
class ProjectRepository {
    def load(id: UUID): Future[Project] = {
        db.run(
            for {
                project <- ProjectTable.filter(_.id === id).result
                tags <- ProjectTagTable.filter(_.projectId === id).result 
            } yield {
                Project(
                    id = project.id,
                    name = project.name,
                    state = project.state,
                    description = project.description,
                    team = project.team,
                    tags = tags.map(_.name)                
                )
            }
        )
    }

    // another example - if you wanted to extract multiple projects
    // (in reality you would probably apply some paging here)
    def findAll(): Future[Seq[Project]] = {
        db.run(
            ProjectTable
                .join(ProjectTag).on(_.id === _.projectId)
                .result
                .map { _.groupBy(_._1)
                        .map { case (project, grouped) =>
                             Project(
                               id = project.id,
                               name = project.name,
                               state = project.state,
                               description = project.description,
                               team = project.team,
                               tags = grouped.map(_._2.name)
                             )
                         }
                }
        )
    }
}
```

*Digression:*
If you wanted to have paging in `findAll` method you would need to do something like this:

```
ProjectTable
    .drop(pageNumber * pageSize)
    .take(pageSize)
    .join(ProjectTag).on(_.id === _.projectId)
    .result
```

Above would produce sub-query but it is basically typical way how you do paging with multiple joined relations (without subquery you would page over whole result set which is most of the time not what you need!).

*Coming back to main part:*

Obviously it would be all easier if you defined you defined your `Project` as:

```
case class Project(project: ProjectRecord, tags: Seq[ProjectTag])
```

then your yield would be simply:

```
yield {
   Project(project, tags)
}
```

but that's definitely a matter of taste (it make actually sense to make it as you did - to hide internal record layout).

Basically there are potentially multiple things that could be improved here. I am not really an expert on DDD but at least from `Slick` perspective the 1st change that should be done is to change the method:

```
def load(id: UUID): Future[Project]
```

to

```
def load(id: UUID): DBIO[Project]
```

and perform `db.run(...)` operation on some higher level. The reason for this is that in `Slick` as soon as you fire `db.run` (thus convert `DBIO` to `Future`) you loose ability to compose multiple operation within single transaction. Therefore a common pattern is to push `DBIO` pretty high in application layers, basically up to some business levels which defined transactional boundaries.

Comment: ActiveRecord is not an adequate persistence pattern for DDD ARs.

Comment: Exactly - that's the whole point of above answer. Your root doesn't (have to) map to particular db tuple, yet Slick basically operates on this level. Therefore you don't keep bare Slick layer as AR.

Comment: I meant that ARs shouldn't access the db. Persistence details shall be abstracted away in a Repository. Well, that is if you want to do pure DDD where the model focuses on the business only. There is no definitive rule, but with complex domain logic you do not want throw in persistence logic in there.

Comment: You are totally right. Take a look at my corrected answer above. (I am not really an expert on DDD).

Comment: Hi Pawel, Thank you for the response. The only issue with this solution is that it can happen only in the last step (result), right? e.g. what if I want to apply a pagination on data?

Comment: Well.. think in terms of SQL. What would you need to do then? For sure it's about different method (not `def load(id: UUID): Future[Project]` but rather `def findAll: Future[Seq[Project]]`. 

In this other method you would need to either fetch `Project` and fetch other `Tags` per project (probably poor as you would have N+1 query problem). Other solution would be to use simply SQL join. 

Basically - think in terms of SQL; if you know what you would do in SQL then you basically know what to do in Slick.

Comment: True... looks we need to do some extra stuff. 
one solution could be paginating the ProjectTableRec and then running an inSet filter on tags and then join them in code!

Comment: The new load method signature is very depend on Slick (DBIO) which I try to avoid. 
To me repository definitions (nterfaces/traits) are a part of domain model and I would rather to keep them framework/lib agnostic as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal for findAll method.
I will add my final implementation here on Monday as well.

Comment: Actually you have no other way with `Slick` - it needs to be dependent on DBIO. This is basically the most common mistake with people using Slick. DBIO goes pretty high in your architecture with `Slick` unfortunately (that is if you want to be able to compose methods into transaction which more often than not you want).

What you can do:
a) alias the type to your custom one
b) have implicit conversation that would change it to other type (and this other type would need to be uwraped by your transactional manager - whatever it is)

Probably something else along these lines...

Comment: Last thing - take a look here: https://youtu.be/zxgWuO1LEF0?list=PLLMLOC3WM2r7kLKJPHKnyJgdiBGWaKlJf (it is kina related and it shows the same thing - propagation of the DBIO outwards from your Repository)

Comment: The code in method `load` is definitely wrong. Please correct it.

Comment: Hey @WayneWang - I don't have this code sample handy but I tried to fix it - it seems that `for` comprehension was swallowed somewhere during some edits.

Anyhow - feel free to do any corrections yourself if you find it appropriate.

Comment: Paging should in general be not a concern of an aggregate. An aggregate exists to enforce invariants, not for presentation concerns. It would be preferable to just straight go to the DB through a standard SQL. On the other hand, my main concern when dealing with Slick is not on how to build those graphs of objects when reading -- that's definitely doable, but how to deal with upserts?

Comment: Not sure, what you mean: "how to deal with upserts?" How is it different from using plain SQL?